# CSV data to two MYSQL tables using Python

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I need to take data from a csv file and import it into two mysql tables within the same database.

CSV file:

```
username,password,path
FP_Baby,7tO0Oj/QjRSSs16,FP_Baby
lukebryan,uu00U62SKhO.sgE,lukebryan
saul,r320QdyLJEXKEsQ,saul
jencarlos,LOO07D5ZxpyzMAg,jencarlos
abepark,HUo0/XGUeJ28jaA,abepark
```

From the CSV file

`username` and `password` go into the USERS table
`path` goes into VFS_PERMISSIONS table

The USERS table looks like

```
INSERT INTO `USERS` (`userid`, `username`, `password`, `server_group`) VALUES
(23, 'username', 'password', 'MainUsers'),

INSERT INTO `VFS_PERMISSIONS` (`userid`, `path`, `privs`) VALUES
(23, '/path/', '(read)(write)(view)(delete)(resume)(share)(slideshow)(rename)(makedir)(deletedir)'),
```

if possible I'd like to start the userid in both tables at 24 and increment +1 for each row in the csv.

SO far I can read the csv files but I can't figure out how to insert into two mysql tables.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv
import sys
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host= "localhost",
                  user="crushlb",
                  passwd="password",
                  db="crushlb")

x = conn.cursor()

f = open(sys.argv[1], 'rt')
try:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:

    ## mysql stuff goes here right?

finally:
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce the number of calls to `cursor.execute` by preparing the arguments in advance (in the loop), and calling `cursor.executemany` after the loop has completed:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()   
user_args = []
perm_args = []

perms = '(read)(write)(view)(delete)(resume)(share)(slideshow)(rename)(makedir)(deletedir)'

with open(sys.argv[1], 'rt') as f:
    for id, row in enumerate(csv.reader(f), start = 24):
        username, password, path = row
        user_args.append((id, username, password, 'MainUsers'))
        perm_args.append((id, path, perms))

insert_users = '''
    INSERT IGNORE INTO `USERS`
    (`userid`, `username`, `password`, `server_group`)
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)
    '''

insert_vfs_permissions = '''
    INSERT IGNORE INTO `VFS_PERMISSIONS`
    (`userid`, `path`, `privs`)
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s)
    '''

cursor.executemany(insert_users,user_args)
cursor.executemany(insert_vfs_permissions,perm_args)
```

---

`INSERT IGNORE` tells MySQL to try to insert rows into the MySQL table, but ignore the command if there is a conflict. For example, if userid is the PRIMARY KEY, and there is already a row with the same userid, then the `INSERT IGNORE` SQL will ignore the command to insert a new row since that would create two rows with the same PRIMARY KEY.

Without the `IGNORE`, the `cursor.executemany` command would raise an exception and fail to insert any rows.

I used `INSERT IGNORE` so you can run the code more than once without `cursor.executemany` raising an exception.

There is also a `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` command which tells MySQL to try to insert a row, but update it if there is a conflict, but I'll leave it at this unless you want to know more about `ON DUPLICATE KEY`.

Comment: I tried implementing your code but got this error `  File "import_ftp_users-v2.py", line 16
    open(sys.argv[1], 'rt') with f:
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Thanks, here's the code.
http://pastebin.com/4DxE7Jk3

Comment: Hm, I miswrote that line. It should be `with open(...) as f:`. I've edited my post to show what I mean.

Comment: similar error, see full text here: http://pastebin.com/v3SqSBdZ

updated code: http://pastebin.com/nm04u3CR

thanks

Comment: Darn it, there was a stray comma at the end of `insert_vfs_permissions`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know the sql statements that you wan to execute, it should be more or less straightforward to use the `cursor.execute` method:

```
offset = 23
for row_number, row in enumerate(reader):
    username, password, path = row
    x.execute("INSERT INTO `USERS` (`userid`, `username`, `password`, `server_group`) "
              "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, 'MainUsers')", (row_number+offset, username, password))
    x.execute("INSERT INTO `VFS_PERMISSIONS` (`userid`, `path`, `privs`) "
              "VALUES (%s, %s, '(read)(write)(view)(delete)(resume)(share)(slideshow)(rename)(makedir)(deletedir)'", (row_number+offset, path))
```

Comment: Tried this but I get a programming error. `_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1")
` See what I tried to do here: http://pastebin.com/gHQkGdHs